# How to fetch C# code from javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, local-storage

I want to store user info into local storage when I click on Login button. Now the problem is I am getting user info when I clicked on Login button. And I have define local storage code using javascript in .ascx file. My code-behind file contents the values of user info and I want to use that values to store into local storage.

Here is my javascript local storage code:

```
LocalStorage.setItem("TestUser", JSON.stringify({
        "Usr_Username": “The username(string)”,
        "Usr_Email": “Email(string)”,
        "Usr_FirstName": “First name(string)”,
        "Usr_LastName": “Last name(string)”,
        "Usr_CompanyName": “Company name(string)”,
        "Usr_CountryCode": “Country code(string)”,
        "isAdmin": “If the user has admin rights(boolean)”
    }
});
```

I want to fetch Username, email, firstname ,lastname from C# code using          `DotNetNuke.Entities.Users.UserController.GetCurrentUserInfo()`

How can I achieve this? Please guide me to this. Thank you.

Comment: use Ajax to fetch user data in JSON format and then parse response.

Answer (score 3):

You can create HttpHanlder and call it by jQuery ajax:

```
 $.ajax({
     url: "/User.ashx",
     contentType: "text/plain",        
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   success: function (data) {
    LocalStorage.setItem("TestUser", data);
   }
});
```

and User.ashx should be look like this:

```
public class User : IHttpHandler
{
  public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
  {
     JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
     context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";
     var currentUser = DotNetNuke.Entities.Users.UserController.GetCurrentUserInfo();

     var serUser = javaScriptSerializer.Serialize(currentUser);
     context.Response.Write(serUser);
  }
  public bool IsReusable
  {
    get
    {
        return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Or you can use WebAPI to create action and call it from ajax. Both are similar and depend on you which one you prefer

Comment: Thanks for reply. Can you please tell me how can I use following code in this:   var _currentUser=DotNetNuke.Entities.Users.UserController.GetCurrentUserInfo();

        var userId = _currentUser.UserID;

        var fname = _currentUser.FirstName;

Comment: With WebAPI or HttpHandler?