# how to call javascript function from ascx code behind using C#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, dotnetnuke

I want to call javascript function which is in login.ascx file when user click on log in button.

Here is a code for login.ascx code:

```
              <div class="dnnFormItem">
                <asp:label id="lblLogin" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="cmdLogin" CssClass="dnnFormLabel" />
               <asp:LinkButton id="cmdLogin" resourcekey="cmdLogin" cssclass="dnnPrimaryAction" text="Login" runat="server"/>
               <script type="text/javascript">
/*globals jQuery, window, Sys */
(function ($, Sys) {
    function setUpLogin() {
        var actionLinks = $("a[id$=cmdLogin]");
        actionLinks.click(function () {
            if ($(this).hasClass("dnnDisabledAction")) {
                return false;
            }

            actionLinks.addClass("dnnDisabledAction");
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        setUpLogin();
        Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(function () {
            setUpLogin();
        });
    });
}(jQuery, window.Sys));
```

Below is the javascript code in login.ascx which i want to call when user click on login button.

```
function myTestFun() {





    //var  _currentUser =

    //           DotNetNuke.Entities.Users.UserController.GetCurrentUserInfo();

    var userName = '<%=username%>';

    var fname = '<%=firstnm%>';

    var userinfo= {

        "Usr_Username": userName,
         "Usr_Email": "",
         "Usr_FirstName": fname
    };

     localStorage.setItem('GoDashProUser', JSON.stringify(GoDashProUser));
   }
   </script>
```

Here is code behind file using C#:

```
         private void OnLoginClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;

            if (loginStatus == UserLoginStatus.LOGIN_USERNOTAPPROVED)
            {
                message = "UserNotAuthorized";
            }
            else
            {
                authenticated = (loginStatus !=UserLoginStatus.LOGIN_FAILURE);
            }

            //Raise UserAuthenticated Event
            var eventArgs = new UserAuthenticatedEventArgs(objUser, txtUsername.Text, loginStatus, "DNN")
                                {
                                    Authenticated = authenticated, 
                                    Message = message,

                                };
            //string script = "<script type=\"text/javascript\"> myTestFun(); </script>";
            //ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "myscript", script);
           // cs.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "myTestFun", "myTestFun();", true);
            //Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Script", "myTestFun()", true);
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, typeof(UpdatePanel), UniqueID, "myTestFun();", true);

            firstnm = objUser.FirstName;

            OnUserAuthenticated(eventArgs);
        }
    }
```

I have tried most possible options to call the javascript function but it will not call. I want to call javascript function to save data into local storage and also want to pass the values of userinfo.

Please suggest me some way to do so. Thank you.

Comment: What's wrong with your previous question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29505956/how-to-fetch-c-sharp-code-from-javascript/29505994#29505994

Comment: Its not working so I need to change the logic accordingly.

Comment: I don't know whats wrong with that, but as I know that's the best solution for your approach

Answer (score 0):

```
 <asp:LinkButton OnClientClick="myTestFun()" id="cmdLogin" resourcekey="cmdLogin" cssclass="dnnPrimaryAction" text="Login" runat="server"/>
```

Comment: Please also explain the code instead of posting only code.